Problem with creating a program to find a user-designated source string within a user-designated target string (masm x86 assembly)
I've been working on a project for school that uses x86 assembly language in order to find a user-designated source string within a user-designated target string. The program will indicate the position of the source string within the target string.
I have almost the entire thing done however, for some reason I can't get the program to recognize the source string within the target string.
Could I get some help? My only assumption is that it has something to do with pointers.
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc ; Include Irvine32 library for input/output functions

.data
sourceStr BYTE 100 DUP(0)   ; Buffer for source string
targetStr BYTE 100 DUP(0)   ; Buffer for target string

promptSource BYTE       "Enter source string (the string to search for): ", 0
promptTarget BYTE       "Enter target string (the string to search from): ", 0
promptContinue BYTE     "Do you want to do another search? y/n (all lower case): ", 0
errorMsg BYTE           "Invalid input. Please enter 'y' or 'n'.", 0dh, 0ah, 0
positionMsg BYTE        "Source string found at position ", 0
notFoundMsg BYTE        "Source string not found.", 0dh, 0ah, 0
continueChar BYTE 0         ; User input for continuation

.code
main PROC
    ; Clear the screen
    call Clrscr

    ; Prompt the user to enter the source string and read it
    mov edx, OFFSET promptSource
    call WriteString
    mov edx, OFFSET sourceStr
    mov ecx, SIZEOF sourceStr
    call ReadString
    call Crlf

    ; Prompt the user to enter the target string and read it
    mov edx, OFFSET promptTarget
    call WriteString
    mov edx, OFFSET targetStr
    mov ecx, SIZEOF targetStr
    call ReadString
    call Crlf

    ; Call the Str_find procedure to search for the source string in the target string
    mov edx, OFFSET sourceStr  ; Load address of sourceStr into EDX
    mov ecx, OFFSET targetStr  ; Load address of targetStr into ECX
    enter code here
    call Str_find

    ; Check the result of the search and display appropriate message
    cmp eax, -1
    je NotFound
    mov edx, OFFSET positionMsg
    call WriteString
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf
    jmp ContinueSearch

NotFound:
    mov edx, OFFSET notFoundMsg
    call WriteString

ContinueSearch:
    ; Prompt the user if they want to do another search
    mov edx, OFFSET promptContinue
    call WriteString
    call ReadChar
    mov continueChar, al
    call Crlf

    ; Check user input for continuation and handle accordingly
    cmp al, 'y'
    je main
    cmp al, 'n'
    je ExitProgram
    mov edx, OFFSET errorMsg
    call WriteString
    jmp ContinueSearch

ExitProgram:
    ; Exit the program
    exit

main ENDP

; Str_find procedure
; Searches for the first occurrence of sourceStr in targetStr.
; Sets Zero flag if found, with EAX pointing to the position.
; Clears Zero flag if not found, EAX is undefined.
Str_find PROC
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push edi
    push esi
    push ebx

    ; Initialize pointers to sourceStr and targetStr
    mov esi, [ebp+8]  ; sourceStr
    mov edi, [ebp+12] ; targetStr
    mov ebx, edi      ; save targetStr start position

    ; Find length of sourceStr
    mov ecx, 0
    dec esi
    findLength:
        inc esi
        cmp BYTE PTR [esi], 0
        jne findLength
    sub esi, [ebp+8]
    mov edx, esi      ; length of sourceStr

    ; Search for sourceStr in targetStr
    searchLoop:
        mov esi, [ebp+8]
        mov ecx, edx
        repe cmpsb
        je found
        inc ebx
        mov edi, ebx
        cmp BYTE PTR [edi], 0
        jne searchLoop

    notFound:
        ; Set EAX to -1 to indicate source string not found
        mov eax, -1
        jmp finish

    found:
        ; Calculate the position of the source string in the target string and store it in EAX
        sub ebx, [ebp+12]
        mov eax, ebx

    finish:
        ; Clean up the stack and return
        pop ebx
        pop esi
        pop edi
        pop ebp
        ret 8
Str_find ENDP

END main

I've attempted a few things to include:

Adjusting pointer values
Debugging the input strings by displaying the hex values before and after pointer intialization
Debugging length (along with attempting to display the string characters during the length and comparison blocks)
Debugging the search loop.


The first obvious mistake is that you do not even pass the arguments to Str_find. How did you debug and not notice this? PS: your searchLoop possibly accesses outside of targetStr.

Just updated to include passing the arguments into Str_find. I still get the same output that indicates the program cannot find the source string inside of the target string.

That's not how Str_find expects the argument. Did you even write this code yourself?

I'm absolutely retarded. I completely forgot about last in first out stack behavior.

Thank you, I fixed the code with reversing the argument input.
